# how to create a navigation bar programmatically

Tags: cocoa, navigation, uinavigationbar

i have a view in which i have table view and when user taps these cells in tabel view it gets loaded another view ..
like this i have view hierarchy and i need a navigation bar at bottom of my view whatever is the view currently visible in this hierarchy and i need to place 3 buttons on it ...
home,about,visit...

if any suggestions appreciated ....

Comment: It seems to be obj-c cocoa, uinavigationbar, and there are several good tutorials and references for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna go through some of the guides at apple.com. You'll find your specific question answered in the viewController-guide:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

HTH

Marcus